# Code has no errors, Database is connected but An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, relational-database, entity-framework-migrations

I'm coding a MVC web application and I'm trying to populate my database using the Code First Migration method.

I did the following commands on my Package Manager Console

enable-migrations -contexttypename IssueContext

add-migration InitialCreate

update-database

then I get `An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

My code has no errors, my database is connected but no tables are shown in the Database Explorer

Can someone please give me pointers as to where I should look or what is wrong?

```
> PM> update-database Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL
> statements being applied to the target database. No pending explicit
> migrations. Unable to update database to match the current model
> because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled.
> Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or
> enable automatic migration. Set
> DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
> automatic migration. You can use the Add-Migration command to write
> the pending model changes to a code-based migration.
```

[image]

Configuration.cs (Seed Method)

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext context)
        {
            var departments = new List<Department>
            {
                new Department { DepartmentID = 1, Name = "IT"},
                new Department { DepartmentID = 2, Name = "Admin" },
                new Department { DepartmentID = 3, Name = "Human Resources"},
                new Department { DepartmentID = 4, Name = "Mechanics" },
                new Department { DepartmentID = 5, Name = "Directors"},
                new Department { DepartmentID = 6, Name = "Operations"}


            };
            departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
            context.SaveChanges();


            var depots = new List<Depot>
            {
                new Depot { DepotID = 1, Name = "Porana"},
                new Depot { DepotID = 2, Name = "Far North"},




            };
            departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
            context.SaveChanges();






            var users = new List<User>
            {
                new User { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan", 
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18") },
                new User { FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",    
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18") },
                new User { FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",     
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18") },
                new User { FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",     
                    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18") },

            };

            users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category {CategoryID = 0001, Title = "Desktop"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0002, Title = "Mobile"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0003, Title = "Menzits"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0004, Title = "XMPRO"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0005, Title = "Con-X"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0006, Title = "Promapp"},
                new Category {CategoryID = 0007, Title = "QGIS"},
            };
            categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Title, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var tickets = new List<Ticket>
            {
                new Ticket { 
                    UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID, 
                    CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Con-X" ).CategoryID, 
                    Issue = ("Test Error 1"),
                    Priority = Priority.High 
                },
                new Ticket { 
                    UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID, 
                    CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Desktop" ).CategoryID, 
                    Issue = ("Test Error 2"),
                    Priority = Priority.Med
                },
            };


            foreach (Ticket e in tickets)
            {
                var ticketInDataBase = context.Tickets.Where(
                    s =>
                        s.User.UserID == e.UserID &&
                        s.Category.CategoryID == e.CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
                if (ticketInDataBase == null)
                {
                    context.Tickets.Add(e);
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();





            var administrator = new List<Administrator>
            {
                new Administrator {AdminID = 1, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL1", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 1),
                Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
                new Administrator {AdminID = 2, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL2", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 2),
                Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
                new Administrator {AdminID = 3, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL3", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 3),
                Tickets = new List<Ticket>() }



            };
            administrator.ForEach(s => context.Administrators.AddOrUpdate(p => p.AdminID, s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

User.cs

```
public class User
{

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
    }
    public int AdministratorID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AdministratorID")]
    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }


    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
    public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }

    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    //Setting up relationships A use can apply for any number of tickets, so Tickets is defined as a collection of Ticket entities.
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Users { get; set; }

}
```

Ticket.cs

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public string Issue { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
        public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
        //Category One to Many Ticket
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        //User (One to Many) Ticket
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int TicketID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TicketID")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public int AdminID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }

    }
```

Depot.cs

```
public class Depot
{
    //Do I need DepotID??
    public int DepotID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

Department.cs

```
public class Department
{
    //Do I need DepartmentID?
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Administrator.cs

```
public class Administrator
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public int TicketID { get; set; }        
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string AdminRole { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add 

            `if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
           }`

at the start of your Seed method

Comment: Post your table schemas/models. If you read through that error stack the DB is throwing a Foreign Key violation for `FK_dbo.User_dbo.Department_DepartmentID`.  Since you haven't posed a schema, I'm assuming DepatmentId is a Required FK field in your User table, and you aren't supplying a value when seeing your users.

Comment: P.S. Post your error as text, not an image.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I posted the models

Comment: @netaholic It opened VWDExpress (Debugging)  So in the Configuration.cs I have an error `context.SaveChanges()` right under `users.Foreach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName,s)); Error is `DBUpdateException was unhandled by user code`

Answer (score 3):

The error being thrown from the DB is a Foreign Key violation for `FK_dbo.User_dbo.Department_DepartmentID`.

Your `Users` has:

```
public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

A non-nullable int as a Foreign Key, which means it's required.

You aren't setting a `DepartmentId` when creating the `User`s in the `Seed` method, hence the FK violation.

So you can fix this one of two ways:

In the `Seed` method you have to create a `List` of `Department` first, and supply a `DepartmentId` when creating a `User` that belongs to that list.  Just like you have to supply a `UserId` and `CategoryId` when creating a `Ticket`.

OR

You create the `DepartmentId` as a nullable:

```
public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

Comment: What should it be? I was advice from another question to do that. I'm not quite sure how to use [Key,ForeignKey("DepartmentID")] as well ! Someone just told me to put it in there.

Comment: And from your models, you're going to run into the same problem with the `DepotId` on `User` as well.

Comment: Yes it's required. So I just have to copy and paste `        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }` above my `public int UserID { get;set;}`??

Comment: I"ll edit my question to include my entity model so it's easier for me to explain. So when I create a user they must have a DepartmentID,DepotID but not a AdminID.

Comment: Argh I actually had  done it but I ran into too much errors so I rolled back a few versions of my code and forgotten about it. I've edited the question, Is what I'm doing correct in the configuration.cs file? I tried running the update-database method and got the same error. `An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.`

Comment: No, you have to create the `Department` and `Depot` lists before you create the `User`s.

Comment: Ok I've done it,edited the question and now i have `Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`

Comment: You're still not giving `DepartmentId` or `DepotId` when creating your `User`s.  And remove the `, Users = new List<User>()` when defining the Departments and Depots,  EF will take care of that part.  And remove the  `public int UserID { get; set; }` from the Depot and Deparment models

Comment: Ok I've updated it but I got this error when i tried to update-database:  `No pending explicit migrations.
Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
You can use the Add-Migration command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.
PM> `